# Crystal Report is unable to open connection

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports, .net-4.8

Hey there I'm tring to view a crystal report WinForms .net framework 4.8 applicaion. Ive tried DSN and Server Name in connection info to ReportDocument but same error is thrown, I'm using SQL server 2019 Express Edition.

```
    ReportDocument SetReportLogIn(ReportDocument reportDocument, string MainDbName, string ServerName, string SQLUserName, string SQLPassword)
    {
        ConnectionInfo ci = new()
        {
            ServerName = ServerName,
            DatabaseName = MainDbName,
            UserID = SQLUserName,
            Password = SQLPassword,
            IntegratedSecurity = false,
            Type = ConnectionInfoType.SQL,
        };

        TableLogOnInfo logonInfo;
        foreach (Table table in reportDocument.Database.Tables)
        {
            logonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ci.ServerName;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ci.DatabaseName;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ci.UserID;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ci.Password;
            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Type = ci.Type;
            logonInfo.TableName = table.Name;

            logonInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = ci.IntegratedSecurity;
            table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logonInfo);
        }

        foreach (ReportDocument SubRpt in reportDocument.Subreports)
        {
            TableLogOnInfo SubLogonInfo;
            foreach (Table table in reportDocument.Database.Tables)
            {
                SubLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                SubLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = ci.ServerName;
                SubLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ci.DatabaseName;
                SubLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ci.UserID;
                SubLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ci.Password;
                SubLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = ci.IntegratedSecurity;
                SubLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo.Type = ci.Type;
                SubLogonInfo.TableName = table.Name;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(SubLogonInfo);
            }
        }
        //        reportDocument.VerifyDatabase();

        return reportDocument;
    }
```

even with this code or `reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(user: "myUser", password: "myPass", server: ServerName, database: MainDbName, ignoreCase: true);` is the same error

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a mismatch between the app 64-bit or 32-bit) and the ODBC DSN (64-bit or 32-bit).

Also, what ODBC driver and what Crystal Runtime version are you using? Not all drivers are compatible with all runtime versions.